# How to limit results of preload of gorm

Tags: sql, go, join, preload, go-gorm

```
type Item struct {
    TopicId       int          `json:"topic_id"`
    Topic         *Topic       `json:"topic,omitempty"`
    BotId         int          `json:"bot_id"`
    URL           string       `gorm:"varchar(250);unique" json:"url"`
    Title         string       `gorm:"varchar(250)" json:"title"`
}

type Topic struct {
    Title       string      `gorm:"varchar(250)" json:"title"`
    Items       []*Item     `json:"items,omitempty"`
}
```

Here is the two models. I want to query the Topics with each have 5 latest items.

Without the limit for items, I could do this by,`db.Model(&Topic{}).Preload("Items")`.

When I try to add some limit conditions to items:

```
db.Model(&Topic{}).Preload("Items", func(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return db.Order("title DESC").Limit(5)
})
```

It will return 5 items in total, not 5 items for each topic.

Actual result:

```
"records": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "created_on": "2019-08-11T10:28:54.910022Z",
                "title": "Topic 1",
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "created_on": "2019-08-11T10:29:26.952614Z",
                "title": "Programming",
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "created_on": "2019-08-11T10:34:16.040229Z",
                "title": "Topic 3",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "created_on": "2019-08-27T14:23:17.766055Z",
                        "topic_id": 6,
                        "title": "Title One",
                    },
                    ......
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "created_on": "2019-08-27T14:23:17.766055Z",
                        "topic_id": 6,
                        "title": "Title five",
                    }
                ]
```

Expected results:

```
"records": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "created_on": "2019-08-11T10:28:54.910022Z",
                "title": "Topic 1",
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "created_on": "2019-08-11T10:29:26.952614Z",
                "title": "Programming",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "created_on": "2019-08-27T14:23:17.766055Z",
                        "topic_id": 5,
                        "title": "Title six",
                    },
                    ......
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "created_on": "2019-08-27T14:23:17.766055Z",
                        "topic_id": 5,
                        "title": "Title ten",
                    }]
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "created_on": "2019-08-11T10:34:16.040229Z",
                "title": "Topic 3",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "created_on": "2019-08-27T14:23:17.766055Z",
                        "topic_id": 6,
                        "title": "Title One",
                    },
                    ......
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "created_on": "2019-08-27T14:23:17.766055Z",
                        "topic_id": 6,
                        "title": "Title five",
                    }
                ]
```

The actual sql it generated is `SELECT * FROM "item"  WHERE "topic_id" IN (6,4,5) DESC LIMIT 5`

It's obvious not the results I want, so how should I get the expected result with gorm?

Answer (score 4):

For postgresql only.

```golang
type Topic struct {
    Title string  `gorm:"varchar(250);PRIMARY KEY" json:"title"`
    // assume the foreign key between two tables are both Title.
    Items []*Item `gorm:"foreignkey:Title;association_foreignkey:Title" json:"items,omitempty"`
}

var topics []Topic
db.Model(&Topic{}).Preload("Items", func(tx *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return tx.Joins(`JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT i.url FROM items i WHERE i.title = items.title ORDER BY i.topic_id DESC LIMIT 5
        ) AS foo ON foo.url = items.url`)
}).Find(&topics)
```

You could use lateral join to limit the rows for each different value. After retrieving the rows of `topics`, gorm then send the following query to get the related rows from `items`:

```sql
SELECT "items".*
FROM "items"
JOIN LATERAL
  (SELECT i.url
   FROM items i
   WHERE i.title = items.title
   ORDER BY i.topic_id DESC
   LIMIT 5) AS foo ON foo.url = items.url
WHERE ("title" IN (?))
```

Comment: can you explain it more?